# Warning Handling COM Exceptions in C#

Tags: c#

I am getting warning when I try to get the value of HRESULT from the com exception and I am suspecting if this is not the correct way to handle a COM exception in C#, please advise the code looks like below.

```
try
{
 ...                      
}
catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException comex)
{
 // Warning 8   Comparison to integral constant is useless; the constant is outside the range of type 'int'

 if (comex.ErrorCode == Constants.E_FAIL)
 {

 }  

}
```

E_FAIL is defined as

```
public const UInt32 E_FAIL = 0x80004005;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arguably it would have been more consistent with the Win32 API to define `Exception.HResult` as `UInt32` rather than `Int32` aka `int`.

Probably this wasn't done because UInt32 is not CLS-Compliant.

I would suggest you define your constants as int:

```
public const int E_FAIL = unchecked((int)0x80004005);
```

Answer (score 0):

`comex.ErrorCode` is an Int32 (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.runtime.interopservices.externalexception.errorcode.aspx)) and your `Constants.E_FAIL` exceeds Int32 limits (`Int32.MaxValue` = 7FFFFFFF).

I see you're comparing an Int32 with a UInt32: you should convert the latter before comparing...
For example you could use

```
if (comex.ErrorCode == unchecked((int)Constants.E_FAIL))
```

Comment: E_FAIL value is defined in MSDN I can not define it myself and yes it might exceed int32 but then how do I get the HRESULT from exception ?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
if (comex.ErrorCode == unchecked((int)Constants.E_FAIL))
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Note, however, that some error codes you will likely never see as they are mapped to [specific exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ztbc5s1.aspx), although it doesn't look like `E_FAIL` is one of them.